# Enforcing a many-to-one relationship in noe4j using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Consider two entities x and y have a many-to-one relationship. That is an instance of x is related to exactly one instance of y.

Moreover, this constraint needs to be enforced in concurrent scenario where several users are updating the relationship.

To enforce this relationship, neo4j does not allow us define a constraint on the number of relationships allowed between an instance of entities x and y.

To enforce the relationship constraint programmatically using cypher, we delete the old relationship and create a new relationship as follows.

`match (x:x)-[r:relates_to]->(y:y) 
 delete r 
 delete y 
 create (x)-[newr:relates_to]->(newy:y)`

The above cypher query is executed using cypher transactional http endpoint.

Using SoapUI we emulated concurrent requests, expected results were:

- Some requests could fail because they are concurrently deleting the relationship. This is okay.
- Because the cypher query is executed in transactional scope, all changes are either  committed or rolled back. i.e. the many-to-one relationship constraint must be eventually honored.

However actual results differ, the concurrent updates results in inconsistent data, one instance of entity x is seen related to multiple instances of entity y.

What could be causing the inconsistent relationships, does the cypher query needs to be tweaked.

Environment:

- Noe4j 2.1.2
- java version "1.7.0_45"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
- Operating system RHEL 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there used to be a feature in older version :

```
CREATE UNIQUE (x)-[newr:relates_to]->(newy:y)
```

i believe in newer versions this has been replaced by

```
OPTIONAL match (x:x)-[r:relates_to]->(y:y) 
create (x)-[newr:relates_to]->(newy:y)
```

Comment: The above cypher statement creates a new relationship 'newr' as well as a new target node 'newy'.  

In order to delete just the relationship and create a new relationship to an existing node newy user cypher: 
match (x:x)-[r:relates_to]->(y:y) 
match(newy:y{id: {inputId} )})
delete r create (x)-[newr:relates_to]->(newy)